# Why my card changes from WPA Handshake to PMKID or vice versa just by airodump-ng

Tags: wifi, wireless, kali-linux, terminal

I am running Kali linux 2020.3 on VBox on Windows 10. I put my wireless card AWUS036ACH chipset Realtek RTL8812AU in monitor mode using `airmon-ng start wlan0`.

[image]

Then i use `airodump-ng wlan0` to capture all the traffic that is passing by. When i use `airodump-ng wlan0` it captures a **WPA Handshake** of any AP and then switch from WPA Handshake to **PMKID**. This keeps on happening while `airodump-ng wlan0` is running.

[image: Image of airodump-ng wlan0 capturing WPA Handshake]

[image: Image of airodump-ng wlan0 capturing PMKID]

Could it be due to the wireless card i am using?

I have got another issue, which i think, somehow related to this. While on  `airodump-ng wlan0` my card shows whole lot of APs and devices, but it is kind of weird that i am just able to see all of them when i am totally zoomed out (of course you can't read anything if you are totally zoomed out). As soon as i try to zoom in, the APs start missing by missing i mean they don't show up on the screen even if i scroll down (and start showing up again if i zoom out).
This how it looks like:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the behavior is bad? Everything seems to be working normally. Also, I'd imagine zooming in and out is messing up the display. Perhaps use some filter options so there are less results and no need to zoom out.

Comment: @multithr3at3d. I think the behavior is bad because at the end i am not getting the output (which is a Handshake). I don't get how  can I get a PMKID or WPA Handshake (and vice versa) with just airodump-ng wlan0 (without mentioning a BSSID or a Channel).
Thanks for the filter option but on the other hand if i wanted to see all of the results, what should i do?